# How to define a symbol in nasm only if it's undefined (so far)?

Tags: nasm

This doesn't compile with nasm, because it's not allowed to define the same symbol multiple times:

```
answer equ 42
; ... (more code here) ...
answer equ 42
```

Is there a way to make the 2nd instance work (and be a noop if the symbol is already defined) without extending the 1st instance?

One workaround I know is using macros, i.e. extending the 1st instance with `%define answer_defined`, and doing `%ifndef answer_defined` in the 2nd instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no solution without changing the 1st definition.

If we are allowed to change the first definition, it's possible to do it with a macro of the same name:

```
%define answer answer
answer equ 42
; ...
%ifndef answer
%define answer answer
answer equ 42
%endif
```